# Filtering with criteria applied to subsets in Google Sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

See [this doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E8mIEu3rxos4Lz8yndfdYOdynuopTfD2nLG2VB1sKX0/edit?usp=sharing) for live example

Given this data:

```
+-----------------+-----------+--------------------+
| extraction_date | seller_id | listings_remaining |
+-----------------+-----------+--------------------+
| 2020-02-03      | 110569676 |                 69 |
| 2020-02-03      |  91489962 |                 10 |
| 2020-01-04      | 120000084 |                  4 |
| 2020-02-01      | 102356225 |                  3 |
| 2020-02-26      | 110569676 |                176 |
| 2020-02-26      |  91489962 |                 12 |
| 2020-02-10      | 120000084 |                  8 |
+-----------------+-----------+--------------------+
```

I want to return one row per seller, matching the row with the latest extraction date per seller, and only if the latest extraction date of that seller is more than 15 days in the past.

```
'=filter(A4:C4,(match(A4,maxifs(A4:A10,B4:B10,"="&B4:B10),0))*(A4:A10<today()-15))
```

[image: attempt to filter with criteria on subsets]

I cannot seem to make it work. I tried maxifs'ing without the match, inserting the 15 day condition into the maxif... but filter function resists all my attempts.

Edit: this is going to be part of an already existing working FILTER function, that's why I am constraining myself to the user of filter and not QUERY or database functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(SORTN(SORT(A4:C, 1, 0), 999^99, 2, 2, 0), 
 "where Col1 < date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-15, "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

or with `FILTER`

```
=FILTER(SORTN(SORT(A4:C, 1, 0), 999^99, 2, 2, 0), 
 INDEX(SORTN(SORT(A4:C, 1, 0), 999^99, 2, 2, 0),,1)<TODAY()-15)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Is there Way to use filter and not query? I would have explained in the question that this is part of the problem

Comment: sure: `=FILTER(SORTN(SORT(A4:C, 1, 0), 999^99, 2, 2, 0), 
 INDEX(SORTN(SORT(A4:C, 1, 0), 999^99, 2, 2, 0),,1)<TODAY()-15)`